# Using a String to find a static variable Java

Tags: java, string, class, variables

I need to find a way to use a String, to get the value of a variable, in a another class. For instance, say I had this class:

```
public class ClassName {
   public static File f = new File ("C:\\");
}
```

And I also had this String in a different class:

```
String str = "ClassName.f";
```

Is there a way I could use the String, str, to get the value of ClassName.f? I don't want to have to hard code each value into a specific method.

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.  However, you should probably use a map instead.

Comment: How would you use that?

Comment: A map of strings to classes?

Comment: `String str=ClassName.f;` this should work

Comment: @XtremeBaumer what?

Comment: This smells of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question where you're asking how to solve a specific code problem when there may be a much better, albeit completely different, approach to solve the overall issue. Yes, you could use reflection, but you'll end up with an ugly, dirty and brittle solution. Better that you tell us the overall issues that you're trying to solve so we can show you the better way.

Comment: Agreed with Hovercraft, you are clearly reluctant to provide more context on the goal of your application, which leads you into the XY thing. If you do this with every feature in your program, you may end up with accumulating bad code that will cause you to start from scratch in the future.

Comment: just remove the `""` from your code and it should work. atleast it does for me

Comment: To get the class name you can use `String className = this.getClass().getName();`. Maybe this solved your problem? Let me know if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always only want static fields, the following code does some string splitting and uses reflection to do this. It will print "oy" when run...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static String oy = "OY";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getStaticValue("StackOverflow.oy"));
    }

    public static Object getStaticValue(String fieldId) {
        int idx = fieldId.indexOf(".");
        String className = fieldId.substring(0, idx);
        String fieldName = fieldId.substring(idx + 1);

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            return field.get(null);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           // BOOM!
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

If your static field is not public, you will need to make it accessible, to do this, you need to add the "setAccessible" line...

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class StackOverflow {

    private static String oy = "OY";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getStaticValue("StackOverflow.oy"));
    }

    public static Object getStaticValue(String fieldId) {
        int idx = fieldId.indexOf(".");
        String className = fieldId.substring(0, idx);
        String fieldName = fieldId.substring(idx + 1);

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field.get(null);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           // BOOM!
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html):

```
// make array to use easier
String[] str = "ClassName.f".split("\\.");

// get the class
Class c = Class.forName("packagename." + str[0]);
// get the field
Field field = c.getDeclaredField(str[1]);

// USE IT!
System.out.println(field.getName());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
f
```

Answer (score 1):

A map, as suggested in the comments, could be your best bet, as in this case reflection might not be the best practice.

To be able to call it from anywhere in your program, you'd need something like the **Singleton** pattern, which has to be handled with care:

```
public class ClassNameHandler {
   private static ClassNameHandler instance = null;
   protected ClassNameHandler() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }

   public Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<String, File>();

   public File f = ClassName.f;
   map.put("ClassName.f", f);
   //Add more files or variables to the map

   public static ClassNameHandler getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassNameHandler();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Then, elsewhere, you could use something like :

```
String str = "ClassName.f";
ClassNameHandler.map.get(str);
```

Double check the singleton pattern for implementation. If it sounds like too much, then there may be other options available but you did not provide much context or what the purpose of your application is, so it depends.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this as part of injecting api keys into Unity3d via Android apps

Thanks to some of the answers here I came up with:

inside **OnCreate**

```
tryPutExtra("SECRET_API_STUFF");
```

**tryPutExtra** function

```
void tryPutExtra(String prop) {
    try {
        Field field = BuildConfig.class.getDeclaredField(prop);
        String str = String.valueOf(field);
        getIntent().putExtra(prop, str);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

** EDIT **

At some point the the above function stopped working and I don't know why. I've migrated to the following:

```
    try {
        Field field = BuildConfig.class.getDeclaredField(prop);
        // String str = String.valueOf(field);
        String str = field.get(null).toString();
        intent.putExtra(prop, str);
        Log.i(null, "PutExtra " + prop + " = " + str);
        field.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```